# Disable boxtrapper via ssh

Tags: php, cpanel

Is there a way to disable the cpanel app boxtrapper via ssh?

I have root access but no cpanel access

tried stopping it as a service, didnt work

I have also tried

```
kilall -9 spamd
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to find boxtrapper config file in filesystem. Find the directory of web server, in etc or something like that there should be hidden folder: .boxtrapper. You could even try to use find for the filesystem. Good luck.